# outputting an array using a class method

Tags: php

I am really new to PHP so please do forgive my asinine question.

Why is my loop not working, thank you?

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/user/Desktop/csv_transformation.php on line 16
```

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/user/Desktop/csv_transformation.php on line 16

```
class Processor 
{
  
  public $arr1;

  function __construct($arr1) 
  {
    $this->arr1 = $arr1;
  }
  
  function get_arr() 
  {
    
    foreach ($this->arr1 as $element) {
      echo "array 1 = " . $element . PHP_EOL;
    };
    
  }

}

$test = new Processor("one", "two", "three");
$test->get_arr();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried giving actually an array to your function (within the `[]`) blocks?

`$test = new Processor(["one", "two", "three"]);`

Comment: oh gosh, that is terribly embarrassing. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You passing multiple parameters instead of single on as you are not wrapping using []. That means you are passing individual three strings. Inside class your are initiating a string. and for foreach loop you are giving string that doesn't possible.
because foreach only accepts objects or array. so pass array instead of multiple strings

```
$test = new Processor(["one", "two", "three"]);
```